# spyder change editor default font/scale/zoom

Tags: python, ide, spyder

Is there an option in `Spyder` to set/change a default script window (editor) scale?

I always have to adjust the script display for each script when I open `Spyder` with `ctrl + mouse wheel` and it annoys me a lil bit.

I searched in `Spyder` `preferences` and in google, but didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Seems that I didn't inspect `Preferences` attentively enough initially.
Right answer is:

```
Preferences → Text and margin font style → Size
```

**EDIT:**
updating answer according to comments.

In the latest versions of Spyder IDE path to changing font size is:

```
Tools → Preferences → General → Appearance → Fonts
```

**EDIT2 (since march 2021):**

```
Tools → Preferences → Appearance → Fonts
```

**EDIT3 (since march 2023):**

```
Python → Preferences → Appearance → Fonts
```

Comment: Right not it's in Tools → Preferences → General → Appearance

Comment: Oddly, it doesn't always affect the console and editor windows the same.

Comment: +1 They removed one step, so you no longer have to click on General to get to Appearance. Appearance is on the main preferences page. `Tools → Preferences → Appearance → Fonts`

Comment: As of March 2023, it's now under the Python menu > Preferences > Appearance

Answer (score 9):

Right clicking in the text window there are menus `Zoom in`, `Zoom out` and `Zoom reset`

Comment: hi, there's no problem in adjusting script display using `ctrl + mouse wheel`, hotkeys or by right mouse click menu. The initial question was how to change _default_ font size for not to change size on every launch, so your answer doesn't really answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ctrl++ to zoom-in and Ctrl+- to zoom-out of the editor.